# how to lock a subscription to a single device?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an app that I would like companies to buy licences for.  Say they have 5 devices so would by 5 subscriptions?

is this possible with IAP?

Is there a way of stopping them just having a single shared iCloud account and buying a single licence which is re-used across devices?

Has anyone need to do this before?

Thanks

Comment: A purchase is linked to an Apple ID, not a device so you have to allow the use of the subscription on multiple devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no, there is no way to do that on iOS. The app would be rejected, with or without In-App Purchase.

11.6 Content subscriptions using IAP must [...] be **available to the user from all of their iOS devices**

11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App **will be rejected**

Ref:
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies

Just so you know:
There are ways for large companies to buy app licences by volume (through VPP and MDM). But you would have no involvement in this matter, and you app still needs to be available on the AppStore.